# Application is not executing

Tags: firebase

I'm attempting to complete the Google Code Lab - Transport Tracker app (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/transport-tracker-map/#0) I've completed both the the back and frontedn, and have successfully deployed. For step 3, it says,

"The last line of output from the firebase command will be a URL for your newly created web application. Please feel free to open the URL in a new Chrome tab and marvel at the beautiful pixels."

When I go to the url https://transport-tracker-backen-ad166.firebaseapp.com/, I get, "Welcome Firebase Hosting Complete", but I'm not seeing my map application. I'm brand new to firebase, I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Have you deployed the hosting files with `npm run firebase-deploy`? That's the last step in the tutorial page for hosting and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, i have run the npm run firebase-deploy command but still getting the same result